# Flyway & MyBatis: Java Configuration for Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, flyway

I'm trying to code a web-app using Spring-Boot, HSQLDB, Flyway and MyBatis. I started without MyBatis and Flyway happily created the database every time I had removed the HSQLDB.

After I added MyBatis all was fine until I had to make changes in the initial SQL-file and removed the database. Now I'm failing to start the web-app. It seems as if Flyway and MyBatis somehow depend on each other.

My database configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() { ... }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() { ... }

  @Bean
  public static MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer() { ... }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() throws Exception { ... }

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception { ... }

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate() throws Exception { ... }

}
```

I fully understand that `MapperScannerConfigurer`, `SqlSessionFactoryBean` and `SqlSessionTemplate` are coming from MyBatis, all Flyway-stuff is done by Spring-Boot. From what I can tell Flyway needs a `DataSource` and MyBatis needs a database where the Flyway scripts ran already to allow the initialisation of the mappers.

The error I get is

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_TABLE
### The error may exist in file [/home/work/Eclipse/com.sjngm.hs/target/classes/sqlmap/MyTableMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.sjngm.hs.dao.mapper.MyTableMapper.getByName
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: SELECT *       FROM MY_TABLE      WHERE Name = ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_TABLE
```

Note that there is no indication in the entire log-file that Flyway already did something. Also I can't find any `CREATE TABLE` in HSQLDB's files, which makes the above error saying that it can't find table MY_TABLE.

I already tried moving `dataSource()` to a new configuration class, but that didn't help.

What do I need to do to solve that indirect dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped was making `dataSource()` a `@FlywayDataSource`.